# Is this percent change question right?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I created this question and I'm wondering whether the "same percent change" is right. Chocolate has a 40% increase and vanilla has a 40% decrease. Is it right to say they have the same percent change even if one is increase and the other is decrease?

Here's the question:

The table below shows the number of ice cream flavors sold from June to October. Which flavors have the same percent change between June and September?

[image]

a.  Cookies and Cream and Vanilla

b.  Strawberry and Chocolate

c.  Chocolate and Vanilla

d.  Vanilla, Cookies and Cream, and Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chocolate has a $4\%$ increase, and Vanilla has a $40\%$ decrease.

Now, I assume that was an error of yours, but to answer your question, no. Percent change **can** be negative.

Percent error in scientific context, though, is always positive.

Comment: My bad. I pasted the wrong table. How would I rephrase the question? My point is that they both changed by the same number (or amount) of percent. Like 5 increased by 4 and 6 decreased by 4. Both changed by the same amount. How will I translate that in percent?

Comment: percentage difference is the correct term if you want to ignore sign